# How can I save data when application ends without save button (automatically)?

Tags: ios, save

I have an application that is based in questions and I want to save, for example, the number of right answers and wrong answers when the application ends (the user turns off its iPhone without application come to background) which means without a save button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly when you want to do the save, your application delegate provides a number of methods you can implement.  They are called when the app's state changes.

Look at `applicationWillResignActive:`, `applicationDidEnterBackground:`, and `applicationWillTerminate:` to see which one matches you needs.

Comment: I want save data when user turns off the iPhone without put the application in background. Do you know  how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use these method for it in appDelegate.m

```
  -(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
     {
         //write here code for save your data
     }

  -(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
       //write here code for save your data 
    }
  -(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
   {
     //write here code for save your data 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your Q "the user turns off its iPhone without application come to background"
you can use below method to save data
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application

{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:

```
[classobj saveHere];
```

}

when app is terminating